# Require JS not working properly

Tags: requirejs

I have made a simple code using require js. but output of another.js file is not coming to DOM.

this is my index.html.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">  
        <head>
            <title>Require JS app</title>
            <script data-main="js/main" src="js/require.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div id="myapp"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

This is main.js file

```
        require.config({

            baseUrl: 'js/lib',

            paths: {
                "app": "../apps"
            }
        });

        require(['jquery','app/another'], function($,message3) {

            $('#myapp').html(message3);
        })
```

This is another.js file

```
    require (['jquery','app/anotherfile'], function($,message3) {
        var message4="hello this is another file"+" "+message3;
        return(message4);
    });
```

and this is anotherfile.js

```
    define(function(){
        var message2="hello world";
        return(message2);
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In another.js file replace

```
require (['jquery','app/anotherfile'], function($,message3) {
    var message4="hello this is another file"+" "+message3;
    return(message4);
});
```

with

```
define (['jquery','app/anotherfile'], function($,message3) {
    var message4="hello this is another file"+" "+message3;
    return(message4);
});
```

and it will work